# Angular default sorting in object

Tags: javascript

I created some object and put key, value into him.

```
var obj = {};

obj.Z = "val1";
obj.Y = "val2";
obj.X = "val3";
```

but keys sorting in object by default. In result order next:

```
X:"val3"
Y:"val2"
Z:"val1"
```

How does prevent this sorting, that sorting was as had put to original obj?

Comment: It's an object, it doesn't have sorting on it's properties

Comment: Yes, has nothing to do with Angular this is Javascript. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) may be of help.

Comment: Consider accepting answer if it is of any help

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript you can do like this

```js
var obj={};
obj.Z = "val1";
obj.Y = "val2";
obj.X = "val3";
var newObj={}

Object.keys(obj)
      .sort()
      .forEach(function(key, value) {
          newObj[key]=obj[key];
       });

console.log(newObj);
```

Hope this helps